# Flexbox call not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a footer that I'd like to organize horizontally with the flexbox space-around alignment.  For whatever reason, the li items in this footer collapse vertically when I attempt anything other than display: inline-block;

```
 #footer {
  width: 75%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

  #footer ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

   #footer li {
    width: 30%;
    height: 130px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
   }
```

The accompanying html is simply:

```
                     <footer id="footer">
                          <ul>
                             <li>copyright</li>
                             <li>sitemap</li>
                             <li>contact</li>
                          </ul>
                     </footer>
```

I've tried leaving the ul untouched and with its shown status to no visible difference.  Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `display: flex` on the footer ul.

Edit: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjKOZq

Comment: Thanks, I believe I had tried that earlier; just tried it again and did not do the trick.

Comment: Depending on browser, it may be a prefixing problem: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Second edit did it. Thanks Benjamin.  You are a hero.